# How to avoid two or several hosts reading the same value when using loops in Ansible?

Tags: python, automation, ansible, devops

I have this playbook:

```
---
- hosts: all
  tasks:
    - command: echo {{ item }}
      with_items: [ item1forhost1, item2forhost2]
```

This results in:

```
TASK [command] *****************************************************************
changed: [host1] => (item=item1forhost1)
changed: [host2] => (item=item1forhost1)
changed: [host1] => (item=item2forhost2)
changed: [host2] => (item=item2forhost2)
```

Every host is reading the same line, where as I want host1 to read itemfforhost1 and host2 to read item2forhost2. How can this be done? I'm looking for something like this:

```
TASK [command] *****************************************************************
changed: [host1] => (item=item1forhost1)
changed: [host2] => (item=item2forhost2)
```

Comment: Use host_vars as they were intended to?

Answer (score 0):

Following up on @techraf’s solution, here is what you can do.  In your ansible directory, create a directory called `host_vars`.  Underneath that directory, create two files called `host1.yml` and `host2.yml`.  In `host1.yml` put:

```
---
echo_value: itemforhost1
```

And in `host2.yml` put:

```
---
echo_value: itemforhost2
```

Now in your playbook, you can write:

```
---
- hosts: all
  tasks:
    - command: echo {{ echo_value }}
```